# If $x(\log(x))^3>y$, then $x>f(y)$. How to find such a $f$?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

I know we cannot find an inverse function of $f(x)=x(\log x)^3$ with an explicit form. But could you get a good function about it?

Comment: There isn't an explicit elementary solution of this inequality.  [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+y%3Dx*log%28x%29+for+x) gives a solution of simpler equation using Lambert-W.

Answer (score 0):

Note that for any $x>0$, one has $\log x<x.$ So
\begin{equation*}
\log ^{3}x<x^{3}\Rightarrow x\log ^{3}x<x^{4}
\end{equation*}
therefore, for any $x>0,$ and $y\geq 0\ $
\begin{equation*}
x\log ^{3}x>y\Rightarrow x^{4}>y\Rightarrow x>y^{1/4}=f(y)
\end{equation*}
In the particular case $0<x<1,$ and $y>0,$ one can get another solution:
\begin{equation*}
x\log ^{3}x>y\Rightarrow \log ^{3}x>\frac{y}{x}>y\Rightarrow \log
x>y^{1/3}\Rightarrow x>\exp (y^{1/3})=f(y).
\end{equation*}

$\bf{Here\ is\  another\ solution.}$ Let $g(x)=\frac{(3x-1)(x-1)}{2x^{2}}$ for $x>1.$
It is easy to show that $g(x)<\log x.$ (geometrical considerations, see below) then
\begin{equation*}
x\log ^{3}x>y\Rightarrow xg^{3}(x)>y\Rightarrow x>G(y)
\end{equation*}
where $G(y)$ is the reciproque of $x\mapsto xg^{3}(x).$

Now, what is $g(x)?$ Recall that
\begin{equation*}
\log x=\int_{1}^{x}\frac{dt}{t}=area\ under\ the\ graph\ of\ \frac{1}{t}\
between\ 1\ and\ x
\end{equation*}
consider the tangent line at the point $(x,\ \frac{1}{x})$ and let $g(x)$
the area of the trapeze passing by the points $(1,0),\ (x,0),\ (x,\ \frac{1}{x%
})\ and\ (1,\ y(1))$ where $y(t)$ is the ordinate of the point on
the tangent line when the abscissa is $t.$ The tangent line is $y(t)=(-\frac{%
1}{x^{2}})(t-x)+\frac{1}{t}.$ Therefore $g(x)=(x-1)(y(1)+\frac{1}{x})\frac{1%
}{2}=\frac{(3x-1)(x-1)}{2x^{2}}.$

It remains to find $G(y)$. I am sure you can take it from here.

Comment: Thank you, Idris. This function is not tight enough. Could you please tell me a tighter one?

Comment: can you tell me if your $x$ is between $0$ and $1$ or is greater than $1$.

Comment: $x$ is a very large number, greater than $1$.